# Mi excel reconoce mi conexión ODBC

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc, unicode

Hola he creado una conexion ODBC en mi pc para obtener datos desde mi excel, creo satifactorimente la conexión ODBC en mi panel de control, pero cuando quiero conectarme desde Excel 2016 no me aparecen mis conexión que cree. Tengo al 100 mis actualizaciones. ¿Cual crean que es el error?

P.D les dejo los screenshots, y ya probe tanto la conexion ANSI Driver como la Unicode, de igual manera ya prove con Power Pivot y tampoco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fijate que te aparece una conexion como la que queres. Fijate si se diferencian en algo. Si no, reinicia todo.. a veces esas cosas asi se solucionan

Comment: ok tratare de reiniciar mi compu, porque reinstale el mysql por 2° vez en mi equipo

Comment: Excel 2016 tiene una conexión directa con MySql y no hay que crear ninguna ODBC. porqué requiere de una en este caso?

Comment: Trabajo de la escuela, es para aprender las diferencias entre tablas dinamicas y de pivote